# Draft Js - Add custom class - Inline Styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm coding an editor with few buttons that allow the users to highlight the selection : change color and background-color.

My entire website can be switch into night mode and so I need those kind of posts to be adaptive style-regarding.

The problem is that custom styling in draft js only allows to add inline rules to a selection where I would prefer to add classes so the rules depends on a higher level.

Is there any way to add custom classes ?

Thanks.